# Removing Windows 7 boot partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

My laptop came with Windows 7 which also has extra partitions for "system recovery"(because seemingly supplying a dvd is too expensive) and a 100MB boot partition. I removed the recovery partition and now want to get rid of that small boot partition as well. I heard that it is possible to move the boot data into a folder in the main win7 partition and delete that small extra partition. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the partition from outside of Windows, such as a Linux LiveCD or Windows 7 installation/repair disc. You'll then need to boot up through a Windows 7 installation/repair disc and run startup repair.

You can [create a system repair disc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc) without an installation disc.

Answer (score 0):

Was the recovery partition you deleted the 200MB Windows 7 Recovery partition, as described in:
[How to Avoid 200MB Hidden System Partition From Been Created During Windows 7 Installation](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/09/how-to-avoid-200mb-hidden-system-partition-from-been-created-during-windows-7-installation/) :

> The additional separate standalone
>   NTFS partition, which is not labeled
>   with any drive letter or path, has the
>   size of 200 MB, but only occupy 32 MB
>   of it.
>
> The small 200MB partition actually
>   holds Windows Recovery Environment
>   (WinRE), which was only available from DVD
>   installation disc in previous
>   operating system such as Windows Vista. The
>   partition holds system files and
>   bootable files that are essential to
>   boot Windows 7 properly in the
>   event of the need to recover the OS in
>   the event of corruption.

Be very very careful not to end up with a Windows 7 installation that cannot be easily recovered in case of major system corruption.

The above article describes how to install Windows 7 and avoid this 200MB partition. The WinRE recovery environment is then stored in a folder in the root of Win7 installation drive, which is what you are probably asking for.

However, because you deleted this partition, the best thing to do now is to reinstall Windows 7. The question is whether you had the boot CD available. If you do, then you can maybe get by with only doing [Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).